# How to write own test result xml readable by Azure Pipline

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I would like to publish a self made test result xml in an Azure Pipline. But searching for the format I only find results, how to publish the different xml's of the different Unit-Testing Frameworks like NUnit. And nothing about how to create a simple xml that can be read by the `PublishTestResult@2` Task of an Azure Pipline.

I have the following situation: An external tool is called from the command line to do a bunch of tests. It returns the name of the different tests and if there are passed or failed.
I am parsing this output to a List of `TestResultEntry`, which has two Properties: name and result.
Now I want to create a xml file which can be read by the `PublishTestResult@2` Task, with the goal that the result of the tests that are done by the external tool, can be published in a validation pipline.

Do you have any information on how to create such an xml?

I tried making a NUnit test result xml in this [format](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Test-Result-XML-Format.html). But that is defnitly overkill for just publishing a name of a test and if it is passed or failed.

Here an example of the cmd output from the external tool:

```
SDCI_TC_0034: ......[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0035: .................[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0306: .[Skipped]
SDCI_TC_0036: ......[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0037: ......[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0038: ......[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0039: ..[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0040: ..[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0041: ....[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0043: .....[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0044: ..........[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0045: ...[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0046: ....[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0047: ......[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0049: .....[Passed]
SDCI_TC_0312: .[Skipped]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded and wrote a TestResultXmlWriter:

```
public static class TestResultXmlWriter
{
    public static async Task CreateTestResultXml(string filename, IEnumerable<TestResultEntry> testResultEntries)
    {
    testResultEntries = testResultEntries.ToList();
    var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var time = SumTime(testResultEntries);

    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Async = true;
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

    await using var writer = XmlWriter.Create($"{filename}.xml", settings);

    await writer.WriteStartElementAsync(null, "test-run", null);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "id", null, "2");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "name", null, "IoLinkConformanceTest");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "fullname", null, "IoLinkConformanceTest");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "testcasecount", null, testResultEntries.Count().ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "result", null, "Passed");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "time",
        null,
        time.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "total", null, testResultEntries.Count().ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "passed",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Passed").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "failed",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Failed").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "inconclusive", null, "0");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "skipped",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Skipped").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "asserts", null, "0");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "run-date", null, startTime.ToShortDateString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "start-time", null, startTime.ToShortTimeString());

    await writer.WriteStartElementAsync(null, "environment", null);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "nunit-version", null, "1.0.0.0");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "clr-version", null, Environment.Version.ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "os-version", null, Environment.OSVersion.VersionString);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "platform", null, Environment.OSVersion.Platform.ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "cwd", null, Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "machine-name", null, Environment.MachineName);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "user", null, Environment.UserName);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "user-domain", null, Environment.UserDomainName);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "culture", null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "uiculture", null, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);

    await writer.WriteStartElementAsync(null, "test-suite", null);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "type", null, "Assembly");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "id", null, "2000");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "name", null, "IoLinkConformanceTest");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "fullname", null, "IoLinkConformanceTest");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "testcasecount", null, testResultEntries.Count().ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "result", null, "Passed");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "time",
        null,
        time.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "total", null, testResultEntries.Count().ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "passed",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Passed").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "failed",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Failed").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "inconclusive", null, "0");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "skipped",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Skipped").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "asserts", null, "0");

    await writer.WriteStartElementAsync(null, "test-suite", null);
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "type", null, "TestFixture");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "id", null, "2001");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "name", null, "IoLinkConformanceTest");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "fullname", null, "IoLinkConformanceTest");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "testcasecount", null, testResultEntries.Count().ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "result", null, "Passed");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "time",
        null,
        time.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "total", null, testResultEntries.Count().ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "passed",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Passed").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "failed",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Failed").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "inconclusive", null, "0");
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
        null,
        "skipped",
        null,
        testResultEntries.Count(t => t.Result == "Skipped").ToString());
    await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "asserts", null, "0");

    var id = 1000;
    foreach (var testResultEntry in testResultEntries)
    {
        await writer.WriteStartElementAsync(null, "test-case", null);
        await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "id", null, id.ToString());
        await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "name", null, testResultEntry.Name);
        await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "fullname", null, testResultEntry.Name);
        await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "result", null, testResultEntry.Result);
        await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(
            null,
            "time",
            null,
            testResultEntry.Time.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "asserts", null, "0");
        await writer.WriteEndElementAsync();
    }

    await writer.FlushAsync();
}

private static TimeSpan SumTime(IEnumerable<TestResultEntry> testResultEntries)
{
    return testResultEntries.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (current, testResultEntry) => current + testResultEntry.Time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In NUnit, you can create your [Result Writers](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/extensions/creating-extensions/Result-Writers.html) and use it to create a result file in some other format. The supported format of test result in "PublishTestResults" task are `CTest`, `JUnit`, `NUnit 2`, `NUnit 3`, `Visual Studio Test (TRX)` and `xUnit 2`. See the detailed info from [PublishTestResults@2 - Publish Test Results v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=nunit3%2Cnunit3attachments%2Cyaml).  It seems that it doesn't support custom format.

Comment: I think you did not understand my problem. The problem is, that I have that output from the external tool. I want to convert it into a test result file, that can be read by the build pipline.   I dont have any format. I am actually searching for the most simple format to implement a xml-writer.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. Is your output from the external tool a readable file? If yes, what is the specific format of the file?

Comment: No it is a console output, I am parsing it to get the Name of the test for example "SDCI_TC_0045" and the result "Passed"

Comment: The output result of the external tool you are using is only console output, not test result file. Based on my knowledge, there is no tool that can convert console output into test result file. It is recommended that you use a tool or task that can generate a test result file, and then publish the test result in the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Comment: Yes my Task ist to implement such a tool. I actually succeeded. I will post the code as an answer.